# Tomcat Server running slow - how to edit server status configurations

Tags: tomcat7

Hi I am really new to Tomcat and backend engineering.  My Tomcat 7 server status is showing a lot of heap memory being used and my applications are running incredibly slow. Per the photo below, what can I do to update the JVM memory amount? I've read online about editing the catalina.bat or catalina.sh files with updated memory parameters, but my bin folder doesn't have either of these files. So I am not sure what to do, should I create them using command line? I also went in and added parameters to  Java. Set the run time parameters to -Xms1024m, but this doesn't effect Tomcat.  This server currently runs three applications and will soon need to serve & host a fourth.

[image]

Any help on this is greatly appreciated! Thank you!!

Comment: There will be an existing script or config file you need to edit. What operating system are you using and how do you start tomcat?

Answer (score 2):

I was able to fix this issue. I did not have correct administrative rights to view the proper control panel. Want to leave the answer for anyone else who has this issue.

If adding a .bat file and setting Catalina_Opts and java_opts doesn't work for you, you must go to this Tomcat properties panel and adjust the memory pools there.

[image]